# which database connectivity is better for beginners in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net

which is best to start developing with Asp.net

Ado.net Or Entity framework

which is best and what are the advantages?

Comment: It is actually based on opinion.

Answer (score -1):

`ADO NET` is easy and basic version of Entity Framework. You can learn ADO NET in just one or two days then you can start learning Entity Framework.

Most of companies are still using ADO NET over Entity Framework because it is easy to modify things in ADO NET. In Entity Framework, things are complicated to modify according to our need. If you have to maintain old websites then you should have to use ADO NET.

As beginner, go for ADO.NET first. Entity Framework is new and modern, you should learn this as well after ADO.NET.